# Nginx 1 public IP 2 local servers

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I need help configuring Nginx to point towards 2 servers on my local network.

Here is my situation :
On my local network I have a Glpi server (172.27.134.16) + a wiki.js server (172.27.134.8:3000)
I would like my public IP to be able to access both servers.

Both of my server blocs work individually, but when they are together only the first server block is executed when typing the pubic Ip address. When I want to connect to Glpi I move it up in the .conf file and vice-versa when I want to access Wiki.js.

Is there something I need to change in my .conf file? Should I create 2 separate files instead?

Here is my config

```html
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://172.27.134.16;
  }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://172.27.134.8:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Both blocks are exactly the same so you couldn't recognize who the request is for, hence the one at random is choosen. If a request to this server comes to `/`, who is supposed to reply? Your setup says both, which is obiously impossible. You need either two different ports or a different route at the bare minimum.

Comment: I figured out the issue.
I changed the second server block's port to 81 and I still was having problems until I figured out that my public ip wasn't allowed to communicate on any other port besides 80. My network admin made the necessary changes and now everything works.
Thanks again Alejandro